# The set of characteristic functions $\chi_x$ is a basis for $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X,\mathbb{F})$

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a set and $\mathbb{F}$ a field. For $Y \subset X$, let $\chi_Y: X \to \mathbb{F}$ be the characteristic function of $Y$, that is the function defined by

$$\chi_Y(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in Y \\ 0 & x \not\in Y \end{cases}$$

Prove that $\{\chi_{\{x\}} \big| x \in X\}$ is a basis of $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X,\mathbb{F})$

---

I want to give some context also:

> For a function $f:X \to \mathbb{F}$, $spt(f) = \{x \in X \big| f(x) \neq 0\}$

> $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F}) = \{f:X \to \mathbb{F} \, \big| \hspace{0.2cm} |spt(f)| < \infty \}$

---

So, as we know $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X,\mathbb{F})$ is the vector space consisting of all functions $f:X \to \mathbb{F}$ such that, for each $f$, there are finitely many $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$.

My rough proof sketch looks like this:

I must use the characteristic functions to indicate when the support is finite or infinite. For example, if $\chi_{\{x\}} = 1$, then $spt(f)$ is finite and likewise if $\chi_{\{x\}} = 0$, $spt(f)$ is not finite. And I must do this somehow for every $x \in X$. Since supports are either finite or infinite, a mapping can be made using $1$ and $0$ respectively.

But a basis is a set, not a mapping. There are a lot of moving pieces here. Any hints or tips on how I should approach this problem?

Comment: A basis of a vector space is a set of vectors that is linearly independent and spans the space. Therefore you have to show that $B = \{\chi_{\{x\}} : x \in X\}$ spans $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$ and that $B$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: @Mason I understand that, but I fail to see how the $\chi_{\{x\}}$’s are related to $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X,\mathbb{F})$ in any intuitive way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f, g \in M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$, $c \in \mathbb{F}$, we define $f + g \colon X \to \mathbb{F}$ by $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ and we define $cf \colon X \to \mathbb{F}$ by $(cf)(x) = cf(x)$. It is easy to show that $f + g, cf \in M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$. Thus with these operations, $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

If $f \colon X \to \mathbb{F}$ has finite support $\{x_1, \dots, x_N\}$, then $f = \sum_{i = 1}^{N}f(x_i)\chi_{\{x_i\}}$. Thus your set spans $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$. Showing linear independence is straightforward.

Comment: Your message is clear, but syntactically speaking here, how can a function $f$ (a mapping) be "equal" to a finite number of outputs (unless $f$ is a constant function)? On the LHS, we have a mapping and on the RHS we have a sum of nonzero values, summing to some value. Is this what is meant?

Comment: @SunRoad2 I assumed that the addition on $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$ is pointwise addition, i.e. $(f + g)(x) := f(x) + g(x)$, and the multiplication by a scalar $c \in \mathbb{F}$ is pointwise, i.e. $(cf)(x) := cf(x)$. With these operations, $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Since $\chi_{\{x_i\}}$ is a function and $f(x_i)$ is a scalar, the sum $\sum_{i = 1}^{N}f(x_i)\chi_{\{x_i\}}$ makes perfect sense and is an element of $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$.

Comment: So, in your answer then, are the $f(x_i)$'s the same function evaluated at different points? Because, if $\mathcal{M}_{fin}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a vector space whose objects are functions, shouldn't you be indexing the functions to indicate function addition - on the LHS and RHS in your answer? i.e. $(f_1+f_2+ \dots)(x) = f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\dots $?

Comment: @SunRoad2 I added a paragraph to precisely define the addition and scalar multiplication. $f$ is an arbitrary element of $M_{fin}(X, \mathbb{F})$.

Comment: thank you for clarifying